# Is it possible to exclude nested configuration from autoconfiguration in Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration

Suppose we have a Spring Boot application and autoconfiguration with several configurations defined inside it

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureBefore(MainAutoConfiguration.class)
public class TestAutoConfiguration {

    ....

    @Configuration
    public static class FirstNestedConfiguration {
        ...
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class SecondNestedConfiguration {
        ...
    }
}
```

this class is providing via external library dependency and all conditions are satisfied, so all beans in these configurations are loading.

Nevertheless, I need to exclude beans provided in `FirstNestedConfiguration`
Is it possible to do it?

UPD: as it's simple Spring Boot application, it runs as

```
@SpringCloudApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

without any explicit @ComponentScan configuration

Answer (score 0):

You might use `excludeFilters` in `@ComponentScan` like this:

```
@ComponentScan(value = {'your.package'},
    excludeFilters = @Filter(TestAutoConfiguration.class))
```

Also, if you want to exclude specific autoconfiguration globally, use properties:

```
spring:
  autoconfigure.exclude: your.package.TestAutoConfiguration
```

However, please, note that this way you exclude outer configuration. According to [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5427) it's not possible to exclude inner configuration.

Comment: I don't use an explicit component scan in this case (see update). I need a more generic approach like @SpringBootApplication(exclude= ... ), but it's not possible to put `FirstNestedConfiguration` here

Comment: @yevtsy Hi! Actually, after a little investigation it turns out [it's not possible to exclude inner configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5427). I left additional notes, on how to exclude globally, but if you really need to exclude inner autoconfig - it seems not supported yet. Instead, you can try exclude whole configuration and replace it with your own.

Answer (score 0):

Does the profile approach works for you? 
Look for `With the @Profile annotation` section

```
 @Profile("ConfigOne")
 @Configuration
```

[Configuration spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html)